# Is there a concept of file locking In SQLite?

Tags: locking, sqlite

I am using five threads to insert data into a SQLite table, and five threads to read data from the same table. I am not getting any locking error.

Is there any file locking / table locking concept in SqLite?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html